# How can I properly open ports for local traffic on a windows domain profile?

Tags: windows-firewall, windows-domain, ports

I'm trying to open port 23 on a windows firewall, specifically a domain profile. The purpose is to allow communication from computers A and B to computer C, all are on the same domain.

When I open the ports and attempt to telnet from pc A or B to pc C using:

```
telnet 192.168.56.1
```

the connection fails with:

```
Connecting To 192.168.56.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed
```

Computer A is my desktop it's running Windows 10, Computer B is my laptop also running windows 10 and Computer C is my server it's running Windows Server 2012 R2. If I turn off the domain profile the connections all succeed.

I've used the following settings to open the ports:

```
Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security ->

New Inbound Rule -> port -> TCP -> Specific local ports 23 -> Allow Connect -> 

Unchecked all options but the Domain profile -> named -> finished.
```

I also added to the scope the local IP addresses of the machines attempting to connect.

How do I correctly open this port on a windows firewall domain profile?

Comment: What version of Windows? Have you gone in to advanced firewall settings in control panel?

Comment: Updated my question to include the operating systems, sorry about that. Yes, I did go into the advanced firewall settings.

Comment: Specifically you’ve gone in to start -> administrative tools -> windows firewall with advanced security, clicked inbound rules then new rule? It should be pretty straightforward from there. If you’ve done that then please describe what settings you used.

Comment: Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security -> Inbound rules -> Port -> TCP, Specified local ports = 23 -> allow connection -> Unchecked everything but Domain profile -> named and then finished.

Comment: This sounds right, however there is an issue with server 2012 reverting to an “unknown” location and using the public firewall rules instead. Are you sure when you said it works when you turn off the domain profile you weren’t, in fact, turning off all profiles or turning off the firewall all together? Try changing your firewall rule to include all locations, not just domain. If it works, change the network location awareness service to “delayed start” and reboot your server, then domain profiles should work, assuming the server is, in fact, part of a Windows domain.

Comment: I guess I turned them all off because I modified the rule to allow it on the public profile as well and it worked. Thanks, mate, that solved the problem. Felt like I was losing my mind. Can you put this in an answer form so I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Appleoddity, it seems to have been an issue with this particular OS. Once I re-enabled the rule to also apply to the public profile the issue was immediately resolved. All credit for this answer is given to @Appleoddity.

To clarify, to enable and allow the ability to telnet over my small domain required me to give apply this rule to the public profile as well as the domain.